# How to remove duplication from my code

Tags: java, refactoring

I have two similar methods. One of them prints something and one of them save somethings. As you can see there are a lot of duplicate code. How should I refactor it and remove this duplication ?

```
public static void printSomething(List<String> list) {
    for (String item : list) {
        if (item.contains("aaa")) {
            System.out.println("aaa" + item);
        }
        if (item.contains("bbb")) {
            System.out.println("bbb" + item);
        } else {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}

public static Map<String, String> getSomething(List<String> list) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String item : list) {
        if (item.contains("aaa")) {
            map.put("aaa", item);
        }
        if (item.contains("bbb")) {
            map.put("bbb", item);
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

UPDATE:

Code was updated to solve problem when method are not exactly similar

Comment: It depends...why do you have these 2 methods... can you share the calling methods

Comment: You could probably use the return value of `getSomething()` to do the printouts in `printSomething()`; I would go this way in order to avoid methods returning nothing (which are not setters ofc).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark sorry for mistake. I mean duplication

Comment: That edit radically changed the problem, now you can't use the second method to implement the first anymore.

Comment: @Keppil I think problem is still same = Remove duplication. Probably it just change solution.

Comment: @hudl: The problem is that you are invalidating answers to your previous question by making this change. You are better off asking a new question then.

Comment: Are you sure `getSomething` should not return `Map<String, List<String>>` or something like it? Right now, the returned `Map` only contains the _last_ item in `list` that contained `"aaa"` and `"bbb"`, which seems much different then how `printSomething` is behaving (showing _all_ items that contain `"aaa"`, `"bbb"`, or neither).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic Interface Action  that have a method action(T t) can reduce the code.

```
public interface Action<E> {
        void action(E e);
}
```

Example:

```
public static void forEach(List<String> list, Action <String> action) {
    for(String s : list){
           action.action(s);

}
```

Now you just need 2 different implementations of Action.

You can use annonymous types if you don't want to create a class.

**If you know c# this is similar to lambdas.**

edit:

Using annonymous type:

```
public static Map<String, String> getSomething(List<String> list) {
    final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    forEach(list, new Action<String>() {
        @Override
        public void action(String e) {
            if (e.contains("aaa")) {
                map.put("aaa", e);
            }
            if (e.contains("bbb")) {
                map.put("bbb", e);
            } else {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    });
    return map;
}
```

Creating the class:

```
public static Map<String, String> getSomething2(List<String> list) {
    final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    forEach(list, new ListToMapAction(map));
    return map;
}


public class ListToMapAction implements Action<String> {

    Map<String, String> map;

    public ListToMapAction(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public void action(String e) {
        if (e.contains("aaa")) {
            map.put("aaa", e);
        }
        if (e.contains("bbb")) {
            map.put("bbb", e);
        } else {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry but I dont understand your example. Your method return nothing so how should I get my map ?

Comment: when you just println something ? I think there will be still some duplication in method action

Comment: yea it will be repeated :\ are the "aaa" and "bbb" elements in a list? If yes, you can compare both lists and the code will be shorter.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the order of which the `println` of `"aaa"` and `"bbb"` appear does not matter, you could replace the implementation of `printSomething` with

```
public static void printSomething(List<String> list) {
  Map<String, String> map = getSomething(list);
  for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + entry.getValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: +1. This is assuming the order of the printouts doesn't matter though.

Comment: hm thx this will works if the method will be the same but what if print will contains: ... else { System.out.println("bbb" + item);  } and get ...else { //doNothing }

Comment: This solution misses the case where `item` does not contain "aaa" or "bbb"; `printSomething` handles this case, but `getSomething` drops it (perhaps it changed when the question was edited).

Answer (score 2):

In a programming language with first-class functions, you'd pass around a function as a parameter indicating what you want to do inside the loop (for an example see the update, below). Java is going to have lambdas in version 8, but they're not quite up to the job.

In the current state of Java, you'll have to settle with something uglier - for example, passing an extra parameter to the method; or you could pass around anonymous inner classes that implement an interface, but IMHO that's even uglier than what I'm about to suggest:

```
static void printSomething(List<String> list, boolean print)
```

If `print` is `true` then print inside the loop, otherwise add to the `Map`. Of course, you'll have to add a couple of `if`s inside the loop for checking this condition, and at the beginning, one extra `if` to determine if the `Map` is to be initialized. Either way, the method returns a `Map`, but the `Map` can be `null` for the printing case. This is what I mean:

```
static Map<String, String> processSomething(List<String> list, boolean print) {

    Map<String, String> map = null;
    if (!print)
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (String item : list) {
        if (item.contains("aaa")) {
            if (print)
                System.out.println("aaa" + item);
            else
                map.put("aaa", item);
        }
        if (item.contains("bbb")) {
            if (print)
                System.out.println("bbb" + item);
            else
                map.put("bbb", item);
        } else if (print) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }

    return map;

}
```

**UPDATE**

For example, in Python - which allows passing functions as parameters, this is how you'd solve the problem in an elegant fashion:

```
def processSomething(lst, func):
    result = None
    for item in lst:
        if 'aaa' in item:
            result = func(item, 'aaa', result)
        elif 'bbb' in item:
            result = func(item, 'bbb', result)
        else:
            result = func(item, '', result)
    return result

def printer(item, key, result):
    print key + item

def mapper(item, key, result):
    if not result:
        result = {}
    if key:
        result[key] = item
    return result
```

See how it works:

```
processSomething(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], printer)
=> aaaaaa
   bbbbbb
   ccc

processSomething(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], mapper)
=> {'aaa': 'aaa', 'bbb': 'bbb'}
```

Comment: this is very ugly example. First name of this method print or get ?? Second you still have void so you return nothing

Comment: The name could be something generic. And the method has to return a Map always, even if it's null

Comment: Good advice. And you could always pass in an implementation of an interface - the delegate pattern.

Comment: your example will definitely works but you must admit this isnt very nice example

Comment: @hudi Indeed, this is ugly. But Java isn't a nice programming language anymore, it forces you to write lots of ugly boilerplate code like this, or even worse, a kludge of patterns and anonymous inner classes. It lacks the elegance and expressive power of functional languages.

Comment: and how to solved this problem with language which support closure (groovy)

Comment: @hudi see my updated answer. Also, I reworded the first paragraph: it's not enough to have _lambdas_, you need first-class functions - in that sense, Java 8's lambdas won't be enough to solve this problem

Comment: hm function as parameter :) very nice.

Comment: @hudi yes, nicer and less verbose than using C# or Java . It's a shame you didn't accept this answer :P

Comment: yea sorry but I ask how to solve this in java. Your example works too but I accept cleaner one