# Duplicate for loops but different results. How do i remove duplicate code

Tags: java

I have duplicate for loops. One function prints to screen the other writes to a file.  Since the for loops are identical, but their results are different, I am having trouble finding a way of avoiding duplication.

It appears that this question is close to answering my own question; however, it is stated that when printing to screen their might be some duplication and I am unsure if that is the case here.

[How to remove duplication from my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171125/how-to-remove-duplication-from-my-code)

```
private static void printToFile(char space, char hash, int spaceCount, int hashCount){
    try (PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            outFile.write(String.valueOf(marioStepCreator(space, spaceCount)));
            outFile.flush();
            outFile.write(String.valueOf(marioStepCreator(hash, hashCount)));
            outFile.flush();
            outFile.write("\n");
            hashCount++;
            spaceCount--;
        }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.getCause();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void printToScreen(char space, char hash, int spaceCount, int hashCount){
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        System.out.print(marioStepCreator(space, spaceCount));
        System.out.print(marioStepCreator(hash, hashCount));
        System.out.println();
        hashCount++;
        spaceCount--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using a `PrintWriter` for writing to you file, move the common code to an helper method:

```
private static void printToFile(char space, char hash, int spaceCount, int hashCount){
    try (PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"))) {
        printToWriter(outFile, space, hash, spaceCount, hashCount);
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.getCause();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void printToScreen(char space, char hash, int spaceCount, int hashCount){
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    printToWriter(out, space, hash, spaceCount, hashCount);
    out.flush(); // Do not close
}

private static void printToWriter(PrintWriter out, char space, char hash, int spaceCount, int hashCount){
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        out.print(marioStepCreator(space, spaceCount));
        out.println(marioStepCreator(hash, hashCount));
        hashCount++;
        spaceCount--;
    }
}
```

Of course, you seriously need to fix the exception handling in your `printToFile` method.

Since you're closing the file writer immediately, using try-with-resources, there is no need to flush the output. The `PrintWriter` wrapping `System.out` must however be flushed, in case it is buffering, but should not be closed, since we don't want to close `System.out`.

Comment: I see I wasn't aware that I could use PrintWriter to print to screen. Thank you for that. I am still leaning how to use exceptions correctly so I haphazardly plugged them in here. This is actually I think the best solution

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
private static void printToFileAndScreen(char space, char hash, int spaceCount, int hashCount){
    try (PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            String spaceString = String.valueOf(marioStepCreator(space, spaceCount));
            String hashString = String.valueOf(marioStepCreator(hash, hashCount));
            outFile.write(spaceString);
            outFile.write(hashString);
            outFile.write("\n");
            outFile.flush();
            System.out.print(spaceString);
            System.out.print(hashString);
            System.out.println();
            hashCount++;
            spaceCount--;
        }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.getCause();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I failed to mention that I am getting user input and the user decides whether he or she wants to print to screen or write to file, Doing both is not possible. This solves my duplication problem and I am noting this for future coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can isolate the for loop to produce a String message that can be printed in one line with either the writer or a System.out.println;

```
private static void printToFile(char space, char hash, int spaceCount, int hashCount){
    try (PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"))) {
        outFile.write(printMessage(space, hash, spaceCount, hashCount));
        outFile.flush();        
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.getCause();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void printToScreen(char space, char hash, int spaceCount, int hashCount){
    System.out.print(printMessage(space, hash, spaceCount, hashCount));
}

private static String printMessage(char space, char hash, int spaceCount, int hashCount) {
    String message = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        message += marioStepCreator(space, spaceCount) + marioStepCreator(hash, hashCount) + "\n";
        hashCount++;
        spaceCount--;
    }

    return message;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, I failed to mention that I am requesting user input, letting the user decide if they want to print to screen or write to file. This allows for that separation. Regarding time complexity can this be duplicated using StringBuilder?

Comment: You might want to use `print` instead of `println` in the `printToScreen` method.

Comment: @kgm You certainly can use StringBuilder if you wish to do so, but the time complexity will still be O(n). The actual cost may vary, but only on a linear level, as opposed to exponential.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try doing something like this -

```
private static List<String> getOutput(char space, char hash, int spaceCount, int hashCount) {
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        output.add(String.valueOf(marioStepCreator(space, spaceCount)));
        output.add(String.valueOf(marioStepCreator(hash, hashCount)));
        hashCount++;
        spaceCount--;
    }
    return output;
}

private static void printToFileAndScreen(char space, char hash, int spaceCount, int hashCount) {
    try (PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"))) {
        getOutput(space, hash, spaceCount, hashCount).stream().forEach(s ->
        {
            outFile.write(s);
            outFile.flush();
        });
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.getCause();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void printToScreen(char space, char hash, int spaceCount, int hashCount) {
    getOutput(space, hash, spaceCount, hashCount).stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
}
```

This way you can separate out your main business logic from your output consumers. Additionally, you can implement and interface which has a "write()" method for different writers. This way is easy for writing test cases.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
private static void printToFile(char space, char hash, int spaceCount, int hashCount) {

    try (PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"))) {
        loop(spaceCount, hashCount, (sCount, hCount) -> {
        outFile.write(String.valueOf(marioStepCreator(space, sCount)));
        outFile.flush();
        outFile.write(String.valueOf(marioStepCreator(hash, hCount)));
        outFile.flush();
        outFile.write("\n");
        });
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.getCause();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void printToScreen(char space, char hash, int spaceCount, int hashCount) {

    loop(spaceCount, hashCount, (sCount, hCount) -> {
        System.out.print(marioStepCreator(space, sCount));
        System.out.print(marioStepCreator(hash, hashCount));
        System.out.println();
    });
}

private static void loop(int spaceCount, int hashCount, final BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> consumer) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        consumer.accept(spaceCount, hashCount);
        hashCount++;
        spaceCount--;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting I wasn't aware of the BiConsumer interface. Thank you. The code is still somewhat duplicated though.